# How can I collect block values in Ruby without an iterator?

Tags: ruby

Here's some code:

```
i = 0
collection = []
loop do
  i += 1
  break if complicated_predicate_of(i)
  collection << i
end
collection
```

I don't know in advance how many times I'll need to iterate; that depends on `complicated_predicate_of(i)`. I could do something like `0.upto(Float::INFINITY).times.collect do ... end` but that's pretty ugly.

I'd like to do this:

```
i = 0
collection = loop.collect do
  i += 1
  break if complicated_predicate_of(i)
  i
end
```

But, though it's not a syntax error for some reason, `loop.collect` doesn't seem to collect anything. (Neither does `loop.reduce`). `collection` is nil at the end of the statement.

In other words, I want to collect the values of a `loop` statement without an explicit iterator. Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: is `break i if complicated_predicate_of(i)` not what  your looking for? `break` can make the `loop` return a value, i.e. `(one  = loop { break 1}) == 1`

Comment: Could you add some complete working code?

Comment: I'm curious why you think `loop.collect` should be a `SyntaxError`? It is calling `collect` on the return value of `loop`. Calling a method on the return value of another method call is perfectly legal syntactically. It is called "method chaining".

Comment: Good question. Note that `break x` will cancel your iteration and **always** return `x` (or `nil`, if no `x` is given). It does not matter that you use `collect` which normally returns a collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write

```
collection = 1.step.take_while do |i| 
  i <= 3 # this block needs to return *false* to stop the taking
end
```

---

Whatever solution you choose in the end, remember that you can always opt to introduce a helper method with a self-explanatory name. Especially if you need to collect numbers like this in many places in your source code.

Say you wanted to hide the intricate bowels of your solution above, then this could be your helper method:

```
def numbers_until(&block)
  i = 0
  collection = []
  loop do
    i += 1
    break if yield i
    collection << i
  end
  collection
end

collection = numbers_until do |i|
   i > 3 # this block needs to return *true* to stop the taking
end
```

Comment: It should be `1.step`. Good answer otherwise!

Comment: Good catch. Corrected.

Comment: `take_while` is *perfecto*!

Comment: When yielding to a block one normally omits the proc argument, so `def numbers_until` is sufficient. Note that `block`is not referenced in your code. A proc is passed as an argument when you want to `call` it, possibly after it is passed to another method.

Comment: All you need for the method is `def numbers_until; 1.step.take_while { |i| yield(i) }; end`.

Comment: Yeah, Ruby does some things right. Its collections rock :)
True, the proc argument can be omitted. However, in my experience it helps to state it explicitly in the method signature. Self explanatory method signatures help the reader (i.e. my future self) to understand the method without having to care about its implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You could write

```
def complicated_predicate_of(i)
  i > 3
end

1.step.with_object([]) { |i,collection| complicated_predicate_of(i) ?
  (break collection) : collection << i }
  #=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: I've seen many good answers without any upvote during the last few days. Is it just an impression?